# What does '<<' do in a C# integer declaration?

Tags: c#, variables, int, operators

In C#, what does the << operator do when used to declare a variable?

```
int layer = 1 << 8;
```

I've tried looking up the operator, but only confirmed what I already understood. I'm not to sure how it is being applied in a way that is compatible with the integer.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation

Comment: It's [bit shifting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1sway8w.aspx), by simple serch you could find it

Comment: Left-shift operator.

Comment: Simple google found it : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1sway8w.aspx

Comment: The operators << (left shift), >> (signed right shift), and >>> (unsigned right shift) are called the shift operators.

Comment: What don't you understand [in the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1sway8w.aspx)?

Comment: "but only confirmed what I already understood" - this may be the key part of your question. But since you haven't explained *what* you already understand, and what's still unclear, it's difficult to know what extra information you're looking for.

Comment: to confirm, if I search "<<" I get "less than", not "shift operator".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The left-shift operator (<<) shifts its first operand left by the number of bits specified by its second operand. The type of the second operand must be an int or a type that has a predefined implicit numeric conversion to int.